# javascriptに関する質問

Tags: javascript

以下のようにCMSのようなものを作っているのですが、id="ul"の内部にある「消す」や「追加する」のところだけ、javascriptが効きません。どのようにしたら、動きますでしょうか。
詳しい方、ご教示頂けると幸いです。

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>記事投稿画面</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>記事の投稿画面</h1>
        <form id="form" method="post" name="insert" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
            <ul>
                <ul id="ul" >
                    <li class="button menu"><a id="title" class="btn_group" onclick="onClick('title')">大見出し</a></li>
                    <li class="button menu"><a id="h3" class="btn_group" onclick="onClick('h3')">中見出し</a></li>
                    <li class="button menu"><a id="img" class="btn_group"onclick="onClick('img')">画像</a></li>
                    <li class="button menu"><a id="text" class="btn_group" onclick="onClick('text')">テキスト</a></li>
                    <li><input type="hidden" name="type[]" value="text"><textarea name="content[]" style="width:400px;height:300px;"></textarea><a style="margin:10px;" class="del">消す</a><a style="margin:10px;" class="edit">追加する</a></li>
<li><input type="hidden" name="type[]" value="text"><textarea name="content[]" style="width:400px;height:300px;"></textarea><a style="margin:10px;" class="del">消す</a><a style="margin:10px;" class="edit">追加する</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="senddiv"></li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div><!--.container-->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function getHtmlByType(type) {
            if(type == 'title'){
                var html = '<input type="hidden" name="type[]" value="title"><input name="content[]' + '" type="text" placeholder="大見出し" style="width:400px;height:20px;margin-top:10px;"><a style="margin:10px;" class="del">消す</a><a style="margin:10px;" class="edit">追加する</a>';
            }

            if(type == 'h3'){
                var html = '<input type="hidden" name="type[]" value="h3"><input name="content[]' + '" type="text" placeholder="中見出し" style="width:400px;height:20px;margin-top:10px;"><a style="margin:10px;" class="del">消す</a><a style="margin:10px;" class="edit">追加する</a>';
            }

            if(type == 'img'){
                var html = '<input type="hidden" name="type[]" value="img"><input name="content[]' + '" type="text" placeholder="参照画像のURL" style="width:400px;height:20px;margin-top:10px;"><a style="margin:10px;" class="del">消す</a><a style="margin:10px;" class="edit">追加する</a>';
            }

            if(type == 'text'){
                var html = '<input type="hidden" name="type[]" value="text"><textarea name="content[]' + '" style="width:400px;height:300px;"></textarea><a style="margin:10px;" class="del">消す</a><a style="margin:10px;" class="edit">追加する</a>';  
            }

            return html;
        }

        function bindEvents(elem) {
            $('a.del', elem).on('click', function() {
                elem.remove();
            });
            $('a.edit', elem).on('click', function() {
                var aa=$('<ul class="new_elem"><li class="button menu"><a class="title btn_group">大見出し</a></li><li class="button menu"><a class="h3 btn_group">中見出し</a></li><li class="button menu"><a class="img btn_group" >画像</a></li><li class="button menu"><a class="text btn_group">テキスト</a></li></ul>');
                aa.insertAfter(elem);

                $('a.title', aa).on('click', function() {
                    aa.remove();
                    aa = $('<li>'+getHtmlByType('title')+'</li>');
                    aa.insertAfter(elem);
                    bindEvents(aa);
                });
                $('a.h3', aa).on('click', function() {
                    aa.remove();
                    aa = $('<li>'+getHtmlByType('h3')+'</li>');
                    aa.insertAfter(elem);
                    bindEvents(aa);
                });
                $('a.img', aa).on('click', function() {
                    aa.remove();
                    aa = $('<li>'+getHtmlByType('img')+'</li>');
                    aa.insertAfter(elem);
                    bindEvents(aa);
                });
                $('a.text', aa).on('click', function() {
                    aa.remove();
                    aa = $('<li>'+getHtmlByType('text')+'</li>');
                    aa.insertAfter(elem);
                    bindEvents(aa);
                });
             });
        }

        function onClick(type){
            var html = getHtmlByType(type);
            var elem = $('<li>'+html+'</li>');
            $('#ul').append(elem);

            bindEvents(elem);    
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 追加したものは動作していますが何が問題なんでしょう？最初から表示しているものにはイベントがバインドされていないのでソチラを消したかったらクリックイベントをバインドして削除する必要があるかと思いますよ？、それとも別の問題なのでしょうか？

Comment: 最初から表示されているものを動かしたいと考えていました。
説明不足で申し訳ありません。。
＞クリックイベントをバイン‌​ドして削除する必要がある
これは具体的にどのようにすれば宜しいでしょうか。
このjs自体自分が書いたものではなく、私もjsは詳しくないので、教えて頂けると幸いです、、！！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「消す」「追加する」にイベントが設定されていないからではないでしょうか。

JavaScriptの関数をHTML要素にひもづけるには、HTMLタグに`onclick`属性で指定するか、JavaScriptの`onclick`や`addEventListener`を利用する必要があります。

「大見出し」「中見出し」には`onclick`属性で`onClick`関数がひもづけられていますが、「消す」「追加する」にはそれがありません。また、JavaScript部分でもイベントは設定されていないようです。

```
<!-- onclick属性がある -->
<a id="title" class="btn_group" onclick="onClick('title')">大見出し</a>
<a id="h3" class="btn_group" onclick="onClick('h3')">中見出し</a>

<!-- onclick属性がない -->
<a style="margin:10px;" class="del">消す</a>
<a style="margin:10px;" class="edit">追加する</a>
```

ただ、イベント設定用の関数は作られているようなので、JavaScript部分の最後に次の処理を足すと動くと思います。

```
!function() {
  var elem = $("#ul > li:last-child");

  bindEvents(elem);
}();
```

イベントをひもづけたい要素が複数存在する場合は、次のように書くと良いと思います。

```
!function() {
  var elem = $("#ul > li:not(.menu)");

  bindEvents(elem);
}();
```

実際に確認していないのでもし動かなければ以下も試してみてください。

```
!function() {
  var elem = $("#ul > li:not(.menu)");

  $elem.each(function() {
    bindEvents($(this));
  });
}();
```

上記のコードは変数`elem`を宣言しているにも関わらず`$elem`を利用しようとしているため動きません。
以下検証用のスニペットと修正したコードを追記します（といっても`$`を消しただけですが。。。すみません。。。）。

```js
function getHtmlByType(type) {
  var html = '<input type="hidden" name="type[]" value="' + type + '">';

  if (type == 'title') {
    html += '<input name="content[]" type="text" placeholder="大見出し" style="width:400px;height:20px;margin-top:10px;">';
  }
  if (type == 'h3') {
    html += '<input name="content[]" type="text" placeholder="中見出し" style="width:400px;height:20px;margin-top:10px;">';
  }
  if (type == 'img') {
    html += '<input name="content[]" type="text" placeholder="参照画像のURL" style="width:400px;height:20px;margin-top:10px;">';
  }
  if (type == 'text') {
    html += '<textarea name="content[]" style="width:400px;height:300px;"></textarea>';
  }

  html += '<a style="margin:10px;" class="del">消す</a><a style="margin:10px;" class="edit">追加する</a>';

  return html;
};

function bindEvents(elem) {
  $('a.del', elem).on('click', function() {
    elem.remove();
  });

  $('a.edit', elem).on('click', function() {
    var aa = $('<ul class="new_elem"><li class="button menu"><a class="title btn_group">大見出し</a></li><li class="button menu"><a class="h3 btn_group">中見出し</a></li><li class="button menu"><a class="img btn_group" >画像</a></li><li class="button menu"><a class="text btn_group">テキスト</a></li></ul>');

    aa.insertAfter(elem);

    $('a.title', aa).on('click', function() {
      aa.remove();

      aa = $('<li>' + getHtmlByType('title') + '</li>');
      aa.insertAfter(elem);

      bindEvents(aa);
    });

    $('a.h3', aa).on('click', function() {
      aa.remove();

      aa = $('<li>' + getHtmlByType('h3') + '</li>');
      aa.insertAfter(elem);

      bindEvents(aa);
    });

    $('a.img', aa).on('click', function() {
      aa.remove();

      aa = $('<li>' + getHtmlByType('img') + '</li>');
      aa.insertAfter(elem);

      bindEvents(aa);
    });

    $('a.text', aa).on('click', function() {
      aa.remove();

      aa = $('<li>' + getHtmlByType('text') + '</li>');
      aa.insertAfter(elem);

      bindEvents(aa);
    });
  });
};

function onClick(type) {
  var html = getHtmlByType(type);
  var elem = $('<li>' + html + '</li>');

  $('#ul').append(elem);

  bindEvents(elem);
};

! function() {
  var elem = $("#ul > li:not(.menu)");

  elem.each(function() {
    bindEvents($(this));
  });
}();
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>記事の投稿画面</h1>
  <form id="form" method="post" name="insert" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <ul>
      <ul id="ul">
        <li class="button menu">
          <a id="title" class="btn_group" onclick="onClick('title')">大見出し</a>
        </li>
        <li class="button menu">
          <a id="h3" class="btn_group" onclick="onClick('h3')">中見出し</a>
        </li>
        <li class="button menu">
          <a id="img" class="btn_group" onclick="onClick('img')">画像</a>
        </li>
        <li class="button menu">
          <a id="text" class="btn_group" onclick="onClick('text')">テキスト</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="hidden" name="type[]" value="text">
          <textarea name="content[]" style="width:400px;height:300px;"></textarea>
          <a style="margin:10px;" class="del">消す</a>
          <a style="margin:10px;" class="edit">追加する</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="hidden" name="type[]" value="text">
          <textarea name="content[]" style="width:400px;height:300px;">
            </textarea><a style="margin:10px;" class="del">消す</a>
          <a style="margin:10px;" class="edit">追加する</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <li>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="senddiv">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
<!--.container-->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
!function() {
  var elem = $("#ul > li:not(.menu)");

  elem.each(function() {
    bindEvents($(this));
  });
}();
```

念の為補足しておきます。

```
var elem = $("#ul > li:not(.menu)");
```

この部分ですが、

> `id`に`ul`が指定されている要素の子要素で、かつ`class`が`menu`ではない`li`要素

を取得しています（ややこしいですが）。
つまり、現状のHTMLの構造に対する依存性が高く、HTMLの構造が変わると簡単に動作しなくなってしまいます。

もし将来的にHTMLを書き換えてコードが動かなくなったら、HTMLの構造とjQueryのセレクタがマッチしていない可能性を疑ってみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！正常に動きました！

Comment: 元から存在するinputのhtmlが二つ以上の場合、一つ目のaタグが動作しないようなのですが、これを解決するにはどうすればいいでしょうか、、。

Comment: 質問に提示したコードを編集致しましたので、ご回答頂けると嬉しいです＞＜

Comment: ※最初に存在するinputの数は不特定です。

Comment: @rei0328 回答を追記しました。`$()`で要素を取得し、取得した要素に対して`bindEvents`でイベントを設定する流れは変わっていません。もし動かなかったりわからないことあればまたコメント追加してください。

Comment: ＠Kazma Arakaki さん
本当に助かります。。（泣）ありがとうございます。
上記に提示していただいたコードを試してみましたが、動いていないようです。。

Comment: どのようにすれば、動くようになりそうでしょうか。
ご教示頂けますと幸いです！

Comment: @rei0328 変数の書き間違いでした。すみません。。。また回答追記しました。jsFiddleで確認したところ動きましたので大丈夫だと思います。もしまた何かありましたらコメントください。

Comment: できました！ありがとうございます。。
わざわざコードまで提示して頂いて、とても嬉しいです。
本当にありがとうございました。